# Trello - How do I duplicate a list ? or alternatively copy more than one card at a time?

Tags: trello

I just started using trello.com for the first time ever and there is one function I can't find.It seems so basic, but I can't find a way to duplicate a list (make a new,identical copy)

I have a list ( a 'official' conference itinerary) and I want to duplicate it in the same board, so I can make a copy I can edit and leave only the lectures(cards) I want to attend.

I tried:

1. Right click on the list,  selecting 'copy list' - makes a empty list.
2. Dragging the cards from list to list - works, but messy, I'd rather leave the original alone for reference.
3. ctrl c, ctrl v on entire list  - doesn't work.
4. Right click on each card, selecting 'copy' and selecting the new list - works, but too repetitive, I've got 90 cards...
5. Automation - setting a trigger that with each copy/move the card will copy/move to a another list or to the bottom of the original list - works nice but again - too repetitive.
6. 'Bulk actions' power-up - not intuitive and costs money after 7 days.

What am I missing ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the documentation of Atlassian for Trello? https://support.atlassian.com/trello/docs/copying-cards-lists-or-boards

"**Copying a list will copy all of the cards on that list into a new list**, including the checklists, attachments, and comments from the original cards. To copy a list, click the context menu in the top right of the list and choose Copy list. When a list is copied, we'll copy card descriptions, attachments, and comments. We won't copy card history/activity (like when a card was moved between lists)."

My guess is that you chose 'copy' instead of 'copy list'